# Powerpoint - EMF - Preserve shape properties

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, border, emf

I created a square in Inkscape, set red fill color to it but **no stroke** and exported as EMF file.

[image]

I open Powerpoint (2013), inserted the EMF file to a blank page, right click the inserted picture and chose Edit Picture. After that, the square had a border around it.

[image]

But when I created the square in Inkscape, I set it to have **no border**. Is it possible to preserve shape properties of the inserted EMF file into Powerpoint (for example, when I create a square with no border, I want it to have no border too when I click on Edit Picture in Powerpoint)?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for future help...

When using Enhanced MetaFiles in PowerPoint:

- *Insert -> Picture -> Select your .emf file* and click ok
- Right click the image and go to *Group -> Ungroup*
- It will ask you if you want to convert it to a MS drawing object. Click YES.
- At this point the shape/image will have a thin outline. Right click again on the image and select again *Group -> Ungroup*.
- Select your elements and go to *Format -> Shape Outline -> No fill*

(When you ungroup your .emf images there will always be an empty/no fill element behind. Make sure to select and delete it.)