# Powerpoint export as emf does not respect cropped images

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, export, crop, emf

I have a slide that contains cropped images.
When exporting to EMF, the images in the resulting EMF file are not cropped.

**Is there a way to fix this?**
(other than cropping the images in an external application and re-including the already cropped images).

**Related**:

[Powerpoint - EMF - Preserve shape properties](https://superuser.com/questions/588826/powerpoint-emf-preserve-shape-properties)

[high resolution image export of powerpoint slide](https://superuser.com/questions/588916/high-resolution-image-export-of-powerpoint-slide)

Comment: What specific version of Office do you have, and on what platform (Windows or Mac)?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg - 
PowerPoint for Office 365 16.0... (in Spanish). Win 10.